# How to compare items in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays of variable length. suppose that a is of length 10 and b is of length 12. I need to compare 0th index of a and b. followed by 1st index of a and b. similarly 2,3,4..

```
if(a[0]==b[0]){//some code}
if(a[1]==b[1]){//some code}
...
if(a[length]==b[length]{//some code}
```

.
how can i put it in a loop and check?

Comment: It is possible by simple for loop try it out.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you have, say 10 indexes and you want a unique code to be run for each one, you'll have to find a way like delegates in c#. But I strongly doubt that you have such a case, it's a higher chance that you've structured your program wrong.

Answer (score 6):

```
int lim=Math.min(a.length, b.length);
for(int i=0; i<lim; i++){
    //do comparison
}
```

This assumes we don't know which array is longer.

Comment: -1 - the `max` expression is evaluated each time in the loop, this is (usually) bad practice

Comment: @Dariusz No. The compiler is smart enough to perform the calculation only once.

Comment: I know compiler optimization will calculate it only once in C, however Java's JIT might get in the way of this.

Comment: @MarounMaroun By what proof do you state that? The JIT would have to know that `min` is a pure function, how do you think it knows it? Your claim is very suspicious to me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It may or it may not - there is no guarantee, is there? I am pretty certain that if copiler always did that a lot of programs would not work properly.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thinking about it again, I might be wrong.. I'll check that, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dariusz Was away. Better now? Some controversy, I appear to have caused.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a variable that hold the minimum of the lentgh ot `a` and `b` and then with a simple loop compare the items with index `i`.

```
int[] a = ...;
int[] b = ...;
int min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
   if (a[i] == b[i]) {
     //do your stuff
   }
}
```

Note that the upper snippet is **valid** only if your arrays are composed of **primitives** (like `int`).

If your arrays are composed of objects, you have to use `.equals()` in the `if` statement.

```
Object[] a = ...;
Object[] b = ...;
int min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
   if (a[i].equals(b[i])) {
     //do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is more efficient than hexafraction's answer since Math.min is not evaluated everytime the loop condition is checked.

Comment: What if he has specific condition for every index of array (I doubt it, but OP haven't really defined what to do)

Comment: @maremp We can't cover all the aspects here.Based upon the hints,logical solutions given here , OP should convert his program in such way.

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan Your comment is unfortunately obsolete now, though I admit that previously my answer was indeed less efficient. However, the overhead on Math.min is not extremely high for a 20-element array.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely:

- want to get the smaller length and use it
- should use `equals()` method instead of `==`

And here is some code:

```
int minLen = arr1.length>arr2.length?arr2.length:arr1.length;
for (int i=0; i< minLen; i++) {
  if (arr1[i].equals(arr2[i])) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What u r trying to achieve, if a is of length 10 and b is of length of 12, then how u r going to compare b[10] and b[11], or u want:

```
int length = a.length > b.length? b.length:a.length; 
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    // compare
}
```